Mac browser not working, but internet connected
I have seen similar issues on here but none of the solutions worked for me.
I have a 2023 Mac Mini on the latest version of Sonoma 14.5
Everything was working fine but all of a sudden I cannot browse using Firefox or Chrome, I get that ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error message.
I get limited browsing in Safari, oddly enough, I can do a google search but none of the links will load except YouTube weird!
I can ping my router, I can ping google 8.8.8.8
I have checked DNS settings all look good
All other devices on the network are working just fine, browsing, no problem!
I have switched from my WiFi to a wired Ethernet, didn’t solve the problem.
I am really at a loss as to what is causing this.
Any ideas ?

Try pausing iCloud Private Relay if you're using it. Also check other VPN or web proxy settings. When checking DNS settings, did you ensure that /etc/resolv.conf contained valid DNS addresses? (Apps that use their own DNS resolver code, such as Firefox and Chrome, get their DNS server addresses from that file, which is autogenerated by the OS.) Did you also check the DNS scoped routing info in scutil --dns to make sure there were no surprises? (Apps that call macOS native DNS resolver APIs use the scoped DNS routing that scutil --dns reports).
